# FOSRestBundle json decode issue

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

Using [FOSRestbundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/), trying to insert data into table using POST and content-type as `application/json`. My `config.yml` has the following

```yaml
fos_rest:
  param_fetcher_listener: true
  body_listener: true
  format_listener:
    default_priorities: ['json', html, '*/*']
    prefer_extension: true
  view:
    view_response_listener: force
    failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
    default_engine: php
  formats:
    json: true
```

In controller added something like this

```php
$request= $this->getRequest();
$form->bindRequest($request);
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

But getting `null` values for all the DB fields.  Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

FOSRestBundle's Body Listener already json decodes the request content and stores it in the Request parameter bag. You can access the json decoded array using

`$request->request->all()`

```
public function postFooAction(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->getFormat($request->headers->get('Content-Type')) == 'json') {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException("Invalid Content-Type Headers");
    }
    $data = $request->request->all(); // FOSRestBundle's BodyListener sets the Request Parameter Bag to the json decoded data already



    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it's Silex tailored, [this](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/json_request_body.html) should fix your problem:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
}
```

Comment: added this in controller and still getting null values for the fields

Comment: Inspect request content, request field, raw request body...inspect ^^

Answer (score 0):

Formtype getName method was returning formtype name,  changed that to table name. Its working now.  Thanks.